# Edit php template

Tags: php, smarty

I want to edit my php template, but I can not get it right.
I use the the Smarty template engine.

My default php line looks like this:

```
{$customfield.input|replace:'>' : 'class="form-control" >'}
```

I have another php tag like, that I want to combine: `{$customfield.name}`

I tried this, but that does not work:

```
{$customfield.input|replace:'>' : 'placeholder="'.{$customfield.name}.'" class="form-control" >'}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which templating engine are you using?

Comment: @TimoSta I use the the Smarty template engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You can't use "." to concatenate strings in smarty. Try this instead:

```
{$replaceby = 'placeholder="'|cat:$customfield.name|cat:'" class="form-control" >'}
{$customfield.input|replace:'>' : $replaceby}
```